# Different quotation marks with csquotes package

Tags: csquotes

For a document in German I'm using the guillemets option of the `csquotes` package. But there is a section in the document where I'd like to use the "regular" quotation marks for German -- "regular" meaning those obtained by not choosing the guillemets option. Is it possible to have both? And if so, how?

To make myself clear, let me add that what I'd like to have is the features of the `csquotes` package available for both types of quotation marks.

An MWE for this follows:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage[
  german = guillemets,%quotes,<- I'd like to have both quot. marks in the same document
  autostyle = true,
  autopunct,
  csdisplay = true,
]{csquotes}


\begin{document}
Written in English but \enquote{meant to be used} in a document written in German.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to keep `csquotes` features, simply switch between the two styles with

```
\setquotestyle[quotes]{german}
```

and

```
\setquotestyle[guillemets]{german}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage[
  german = guillemets,%quotes,<- I'd like to have both quot. marks in the same document
  autostyle = true,
  autopunct,
  csdisplay = true,
]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
Written in English but \enquote{meant to be used} in a document written in German.

\setquotestyle[quotes]{german}
Written in English but \enquote{meant to be used} in a document written in German.

\setquotestyle[guillemets]{german}
Written in English but \enquote{meant to be used} in a document written in German.

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Otherwise, you can always use `\glqq` and `\grqq`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage[
  german = guillemets,%quotes,<- I'd like to have both quot. marks in the same document
  autostyle = true,
  autopunct,
  csdisplay = true,
]{csquotes}

\newcommand{\defaultquote}[1]{\glqq #1\grqq}

\begin{document}
Written in English but \enquote{meant to be used} in a document written in German.

Written in English but \defaultquote{meant to be used} in a document written in  German.

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Right, but the drawback is that then I don't have the features of the `csquotes` package available for the guillemets anymore, which is what I meant. Maybe I should have made myself more clear about this point in my OP.

Comment: @Marcos Of course. Added another possibility in the answer which exploits the features of `csquotes` as a first choice.

Comment: Good. I had overlooked this setup possibility. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Marcos Not at all.