# Polyglossia interferes with csquotes' ability to automatically switch between quotation styles

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, csquotes

I am working on a document that uses both the `polyglossia` and the `csquotes` package. However `polyglossia` stops the automatic switch between quotation styles (according to the selected language) from working. If we take the example from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281280/182643) and additionally load the `polyglossia` package, the quotation style remains the same:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{french, american, ngerman, spanish}
%\DeclareQuoteStyle{ngerman}%
%  {\quotedblbase}
%  {\textquotedblright}
%  [0.05em]
%  {\textquoteleft}
%  {\textquoteright}

\begin{document}
  \enquote{UK English} 
  \selectlanguage{american} \enquote{US English} 
  \selectlanguage{spanish} \enquote{Spanish} 
  \selectlanguage{french} \enquote{Français} 
  \selectlanguage{ngerman} \enquote{Deutsche}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that compared to the original example, I have also already removed the language options from the `\documentclass` command, since they would interfere with the `\setotherlanguages` command of the `polyglossia` package, resulting in an error ("*Command \textspanish already defined.*").

I also alredy removed the `autostyle` option of the `csquotes` package, since for some reason, the package ends up not knowing the appropriate styles ("*No style for language ''.*", even though according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387523/182643), it's supposed to do the trick):

[image]

A similar problem was reported [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166343/182643), which is why I tried redefining the corresponding quotation styles as suggested in the answer, however it doesn't have any effect.

(**EDIT:** I also removed the `fontenc`, `inputenc`, and `babel` packages from the original example.)

Comment: Don't load both `babel` and `polyglossia`. Either one of them is enough.

Comment: why don't you simply use babel? It will work fine with xelatex and your languages.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. As I've already pointed out in another comment, loading `babel` is simply a remnant of the original MWE. I didn't know how it relates to `polyglossia` and that I should only use either one. I've removed it now, but that doesn't have any effect. In the original project, which is mostly legacy code that I shouldn't tamper with, `polyglossia` is used (and `babel` isn't loaded as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `autostyle` option of csquotes. But you should set the languages so that `\babelname` has the correct value:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguages{french,spanish}
\setotherlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\begin{document}
  \babelname: \enquote{UK English}
  \selectlanguage[variant=american]{english}\babelname:  \enquote{US English}
  \selectlanguage{spanish}\babelname:  \enquote{Spanish}
  \selectlanguage{french}\babelname:  \enquote{Français}
  \selectlanguage{german}\babelname:  \enquote{Deutsche}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah thank you! Why is there a space after "french" though?

Comment: @mapf In French typographic convention there are spaces before (as well as after) some punctuation marks. `polyglossia` automatically adds spaces before colons if it is set to French to make sure things look correct.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I found that the only thing that worked is to use the `\setquotestyle` command, as suggested in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223392/182643):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{french, american, ngerman, spanish}

\begin{document}
  \setquotestyle[british]{english} \enquote{UK English} 
  \setquotestyle[american]{english} \enquote{US English} 
  \selectlanguage{spanish} \setquotestyle[spanish]{spanish} \enquote{Spanish}
  \selectlanguage{french} \setquotestyle[guillemets]{french} \enquote{Français}
  \selectlanguage{ngerman} \setquotestyle[quotes]{german} \enquote{Deutsche}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a rather ugly solution though, and I'm not sure why it even works or is necessary in the first place.

Comment: if you are using polyglossia you must be using luatex or xetex so never have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` or `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: I see, thanks! I didn't know that. I just copied the code from the example. Removing the commands doesn't seem to change anything though.

Comment: the terminal and log both say `Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.` (inputenc does nothing other than make that warning, loading fontenc can completely break xelatex font handling and line breaking)

Comment: also are you sure you want to load both babel and polyglossia at the same time?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! But you're asking the wrong question, loading `balbel` is also simply a remnant from the original MWE. I don't know how it relates to `polyglossia`, so I didn't know I should have removed it. Removing it doesn't change anything either though. In the project I'm working on `babel` isn't loaded as far as I can tell (it's legacy code that I didn't write).

Comment: babel is the standard latex language switch mechanism and polyglossia is an alternative, they are both trying to do the same thing, I doubt that loading them both can have a good outcome.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. Thanks! I think I've removed all the incompatibilities now though, but the problem remains (thankfully the solution also still works). Since it's legacy code (and a pretty expansive one at that), unfortunately I cannot simply switch to `babel`, because I don't know what that might entail elsewhere.